# Are there multiple types of "components" in the study of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vector-spaces, vectors

In class we were taught how to write any vector in "component form" as $(a, b)$, where $a$ is "change in x" and $b$ is "change in y."

However, yesterday we were also taught how to "decompose" a vector into its "components," involving methods like projection:

[image]

What, if anything, is the relationship between these two apparently different definitions of a "vector component"? Or is there in fact no difference? I'm confused why the terminology is used in both contexts, and in turn I think that means I don't entirely understand the underlying concepts themselves.

Comment: You are right that there is variation in how the notion of components is applied to vector spaces.  An introductory class in linear algebra will present the example of Cartesian coordinates and "change of basis" matrices, which effectively give the tools for translating one system of components to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually the same thing.

In the first usage of the word, you find that the components you get are exactly equal to the $x$ and $y$ co-ordinates of the vector $u$. You have found the components of $u$ in the $x$ direction and in the $y$ direction, but to save breath, we don't say this in full.

In the second usage, it is perhaps not intuitively clear how the $x$ and $y$ components of $u$ combine to give the $v$ component of $u$. The dot product formula gives this. In fact, if you changed your co-ordinate system from units of $x$ and $y$ into units of $v$ and $v_\perp$, where $v_{\perp}$ is perpendicular to $v$, then you'd get $$u=av+bv_\perp\tag1$$ for some numbers $a,b$. Then $a$ is the component of $u$ in the direction of $v$. In this new co-ordinate system, (called a basis), one can write $u=(a,b)$ as a short-hand for the expression $(1)$. Then, this looks exactly like the first usage of the word components.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the "component" of a vector in a certain direction is to what extent that vector is pointing in that direction.

So the usual notation $\vec{v}=(x,y)$ says the vector is pointing "$x$ units" in the direction of the $x$-axis, and "$y$ units" in the direction of the $y$-axis.  Notice that $x$ and $y$ are also the projection of $\vec{v}$ onto the usual axes.  So $\vec{v}=(proj_{(1,0)}(\vec{v}) \, , \,proj_{(0,1)}(\vec{v}))$

Similarly in your examples, the component of $\vec{v}$ in the direction of some vector $\vec{u}$ is the projection $proj_{\vec{u}}(\vec{v})$